# setting up Postgres with wsl

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux, postgresql

So I recently came across wsl and was trying to configure postgres with it but I am not able to do so, I am following these instruction - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-database
but when I run the command:
`sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib`
I receive this error -

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-13 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-13
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have gone through some other answers related to this issue too and have tried running-

`sudo aptitude install postgresql postgresql-contrib`
output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libllvm6.0{a} libpq5{ab} postgresql postgresql-13{ab} postgresql-client-13{ab} postgresql-contrib sysstat{a}
0 packages upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 32.3 MB of archives. After unpacking 121 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq5 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 postgresql-13 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

                 Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 postgresql-client-13 : Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

                        Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libpq5 [Not Installed]
2)     postgresql [Not Installed]
3)     postgresql-13 [Not Installed]
4)     postgresql-client-13 [Not Installed]
5)     postgresql-contrib [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

how should I solve this?
I am using windows11, wsl 2(ubuntu)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I'm not sure if it matters or not, but which Ubuntu release are you using under WSL?  20.04 (currently the default)?  22.04?  Or something else?  Thanks.

Comment: I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04